# Efficient search

Tags: r, search

I have written the following code

```
a<-matrix(0,1,nrow = nrow(x))
for(i in 1:nrow(x)){
  for(j in 1:nrow(y)){
   if((y[j,3] > x[i,2]) & (y[j,2] == x[i,1])){
     a[i,]<- y[j,4]
     i<- i+1
   }
  }
```

x looks something like:

```
x1  x2
401 4
401 38
401 142...
```

and y looks like

```
 y1 y2   y3    y4
  1 401 10  22.152
  2 401 40  167.986
  3 401 70  393.198
  4 401 100 923
  5 401 120 923
  6 401 140 686.712
  7 401 160 865.774...
```

I want `a` to be:

```
22.152
167.986
865.774...
```

where `nrow(y) > nrow(x)` is `TRUE`. Is it possible to make this more efficient?

Comment: Can you give some (small) examples of what the data in `x` and `y` look like, and that will show what the code actually does?

Comment: @Marius Is it clear?

Comment: How would your for-loop work when `nrow(y) > nrow(x)`?

Comment: I stop the code and checked the values, and 0's were filled by the number I desired, but it is taking too much time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `data.table`, we join `on` 'x1', 'y1' from 'x' and 'y', specify the `i` as `y3 > x2`, grouped by 'x1' and 'x2', get the first row

```
library(data.table)
setDT(x)[y, on = .(x1 = y2), allow.cartesian = TRUE][y3 > x2, head(.SD, 1) , .(x1, x2)]
#    x1  x2 y1  y3      y4
#1: 401   4  1  10  22.152
#2: 401  38  2  40 167.986
#3: 401 142  7 160 865.774
```

#### data

```
x <- read.table(text = "
  x1  x2
401 4
401 38
401 142", header = TRUE)

y <- read.table(text = "
y1 y2   y3    y4
1 401 10  22.152
2 401 40  167.986
3 401 70  393.198
4 401 100 923
5 401 120 923
6 401 140 686.712
7 401 160 865.774", header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Inconsistency in the col names was the issue, your code works just fine!Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We can merge then filter, using dplyr

```
library(dplyr)

left_join(x, y, by = c("x1" = "y2")) %>% 
  filter(y3 > x2) %>% 
  arrange(y3) %>% 
  group_by(x1, x2) %>% 
  slice(1) 

# Source: local data frame [3 x 5]
# Groups: x1, x2 [3]
# 
#      x1    x2    y1    y3      y4
#   <int> <int> <int> <int>   <dbl>
# 1   401     4     1    10  22.152
# 2   401    38     2    40 167.986
# 3   401   142     7   160 865.774
```

## data

```
x <- read.table(text = "
  x1  x2
401 4
401 38
401 142", header = TRUE)

y <- read.table(text = "
y1 y2   y3    y4
1 401 10  22.152
2 401 40  167.986
3 401 70  393.198
4 401 100 923
5 401 120 923
6 401 140 686.712
7 401 160 865.774", header = TRUE)
```

Comment: I get the following error `Error in filter_impl(.data, dots) : 
  incorrect length (37286), expecting: 2997729`

Comment: @Jamil with provided example data there is no error. Please provide data that would replicate the error.

Comment: Does it makes a difference using read.csv() instead?Also I am not reading as a text.

Comment: @Jamil You should already have `x` and `y` on your workspace. I am using `read.table(text = " ... ` so that I have `x` and `y` for testing.